# How to solve this system of nonlinear ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have $a,b,c,d$, functions of $x$, such that

$a_x=-d-4acd$
$b_x=c+4bcd$
$c_x=b+4abc$
$d_x=-a-4abd$

I've already discovered that $(ab+cd)_x=0$, which I believe may be helpful.

I've tried taking second derivatives of the above in an attempt to reduce the number of variables, but this didn't lead anywhere for me.

Edit: The boundary conditions are that $a\rightarrow\pm a_0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$, where $a_0$ is a constant, and similarly for $b,c,d$.

Comment: $(4abcd+ac+bd)_x$=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your system through a sequence of variable transformations. First, based on your discovery and that of @Michael, it seems reasonable to define
\begin{equation}
x = a b,\quad y = a c,\quad z = c d,\quad w = b d
\end{equation}
and write the system in terms of those variables. Then, we introduce
\begin{equation}
A = x + z,\quad B = x-z,\quad C = y+w,\quad D = y-w
\end{equation}
to yield $A'=0$, which you found. @Michael ' s observation then boils down to $C = B^2 + k$, with $k$ a constant. The only two remaining free variables $B$ and $D$ can be used to obtain the following second order equation for $B$:
\begin{equation}
B'' = 4 B (1 +2 k +2 B^2),
\end{equation}
which should be straightforward to analyse.

Comment: Can we solve for $B$ explicitly, and then use that to somehow find expressions for $a,b,c,d$? From what I've tried, it seems quite unwieldy.

Comment: Would boundary conditions help? I've edited them into the question.

Comment: Yes, you can solve for $B$ explicitly, and use that to find expressions for $a,b,c,d$ by following the transformations `backwards'. Your boundary conditions translate to the observation that you're looking for a connection between two equilibria in the two-dimensional dynamical system $B' = 2D, D' = 2B(1+2k+2B^2)$. Depending on the value of $k$, you can find how many equilibria there are (and where), thereby fixing the values of $a_0,b_0,c_0,d_0$ in terms of $k$. As for the unwieldyness: this is as elegant as it gets, I'm afraid.

Comment: You also have $xz=yw$, or $A^2-B^2=C^2-D^2$, so you might get a first-order differential equation out of it.  But you can't calculate $a$ from $x,y,z,w$; you have lost a variable and I can't see how to pick it up again.

Comment: @Michael: Agree, another simplification yields the first order ODE $C' = 4C(C+1)(C+A^2)$. The fact that a variable is `lost' in the rescaling process can be seen as a result from the fact that the original system has a scale invariance $(a,b,c,d) \to (\lambda a, \frac{1}{\lambda} b,\frac{1}{\lambda} c,\lambda d)$. This scale invariance is reflected in the choice of $x,y,z,w$.